# Is there way to count descendent relational models with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There is a Project model, which has and belongs to associate_project: alias of Project model, and has and belongs to many documents.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Project to Proejct associations
  # parent project => associate projects = @project.associate_projects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :associate_projects, 
    :foreign_key => 'project_id', 
    :association_foreign_key => 'associate_project_id', 
    :join_table => 'associate_projects_projects',
    :class_name => 'Project', 
    :after_add => :increment_counters, 
    :after_remove => :decrement_counters

  # associate projects => parent projects = @project.projects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, 
    :foreign_key => 'associate_project_id',
    :association_foreign_key => 'project_id',
    :join_table => 'associate_projects_projects'

  has_and_belongs_to_many :docs

end
```

Project model is able to have descendent projects and there's no limitation of how many descendent can have.

```
Project id:1

 Project id:2
   Document id:1 project_id:2

   Project id:4
     Document id:3 project_id:4


 Project id:3
   Document id:2 project_id:3

   Project id:4
     Document id:3 project_id:4
```

Project 2,3 is belongs to Project 1 and Proeject 4 is belongs to Project 2 and 3.
In this case, I want to count documents which belongs to Project 2, 3 and 4 as Project 1's documents. The count of documents of Project must be 3, since Document 3 is duplicative.

Is there way to count all counts of documents of unlimited nested children projects?
I guess it is impossible since there is no limitation of how many descendents can have...

Comment: It could be done, but as it it's recursive, could get expensive. Also have to deal with circularity. e.g P1 => P2 = P1. Another model for counts might be a way to go.

Comment: yup, recursive method can get heavy. Better use some gem like `ancestry` or `awesome_nested_set` to better deal with hierarchies persistence (allows to select a whole subtree in only one SQL query). After that, all you have to do is to SELECT DISTINCT documents joined with projects that are in the subtree.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
I'll try `ancestry` gem. It looks useful.

Comment: I've tried  `ancestry` but child cannot have multiple parents, like Project 4 at sample...